# Heroku-based Rails App with an External Subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, dns

Despite the long list of tickets on this subject, so far an answer eludes me.

I have a client with a rails app at `www.clientapp.com`, which is properly pointed at the heroku SSL DNS target. This app also uses cloudfront and cloudflare.

What I need to do now is point a subdomain at a different third party (call it a blog or something).

I've gone in and added the subdomain and third-party CNAME in **route 53** and 24 hours later I get an SSL error when I visit the URL and when I look up the CNAME I see `subdomain.herokussl.com` instead of this different third party. The same CNAME as the main app in the root.

Stabbing in the dark, I also added the subdomain **in the domain registrar**, pointing at the CNAME. Did not work, same as above.

Then I figured I'd have to **go into heroku** and add it under the custom domain settings but hours later upon CNAME lookup, it too showed the same `subdomain.herokussl.com` as the app in the root.

I'm wondering whether I need to set the CNAME via the CLI as follows?

```
heroku domains:add   --appname   cname   new-subdomain.clientapp.com
```

Or is there some other zone configuration I need to set in AWS?

Comment: Without having the real name of the domain and subdomain to check, it's hard to debug the problem and provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer is relatively simple. The issue lies with cloudflare.

Since cloudflare basically sits between the "user" and the site as a sort of caching mechanism / security layer, it stands to reason that they'd be the "gatekeeper".

I totally missed the fact that as a means to achieve what they do, cloudflare actually requires you to use their name servers to begin with! I should have seen this when I went into the registrar to fiddle with the subdomain yesterday but it was a hasty stab in the dark and I didn't think it through.

Hope this is helpful to anyone confused about cloudflare + DNS!